# Client can't send second execution to server

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server-client program in Java. The server do some basic calculations and send the result to the client. Before that the client has to send the operation and the values. I can run sucessfully one time, but when I insert second operation and values I get null has a result. Why this happens?

Server

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

private static final int PORT = 9001;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("O servidor está a correr...");
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    listener.setSoTimeout(0);
    try{
        while(true){
            new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    }finally{
        listener.close();
        System.out.println("Servidor fechou!");
    }
}

private static class Handler extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public Handler(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            while(true){
                String line = in.readLine();
                System.out.print(line);
                double result = parseExecution(line);
                out.write("" + result + "\n");
                out.close();
                in.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.flush();


    }

    private double parseExecution(String line) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double result = 0;
                String [] elements = line.split(":");
                if (elements.length != 3){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("parsing error!");
                }
                double firstValue = 0;
                double secondValue = 0;
                try{
                    firstValue = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);
                    secondValue = Double.parseDouble(elements[2]);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid arguments!");
                }
            switch (elements[0].charAt(0)) {
            case '+':
                result = firstValue + secondValue;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = firstValue - secondValue;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = firstValue * secondValue;
                break;
            case '/':
                if(secondValue != 0)
                result = firstValue / secondValue;
                break;
            default: 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid math operation!");
            }
            return result;
        }
}
}
```

Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.xml.bind.helpers.ParseConversionEventImpl;

public class MathClient {

private String getServerAddress(){
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduza IP do Servidor", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}

private void run() throws IOException {
    String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
    int port = 9001;

    // criar a socket

    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader op = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedReader valor1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedReader valor2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Operação(+,-,*,/): ");
        String operacao = op.readLine();
        System.out.println("Primeiro valor: ");
        String primeiroValor = valor1.readLine();
        System.out.println("Segundo valor: ");
        String segundoValor = valor2.readLine();
        writer.write(operacao+":"+primeiroValor+":"+segundoValor);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        //double resultado = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    MathClient client = new MathClient();
    client.run();
}

}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Inside the run() method I'm doing a while cycle. But now I'm getting an error saying Stream Closed. When I tried to put `in.close()` outside the while cycle it gives me another error and to remove the `in.close()`.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at MathFinal.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:41)
```

Line 41 is: `String line = in.readLine();`

Comment: Just a quick suggestion. Your Client is running in a loop but your Server is not. So after the first time Server may terminate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I did what you said, but now I'm getting an error. I edited my original post with the details, if you can take a look. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code and it's working using Java 7 try-with-resources. Here is the significant snippet:

```
private static class Handler extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;

    public Handler(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run(){
        try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)) {
            while(true){
                String line = in.readLine();
                System.out.print(line);
                double result = parseExecution(line);
                out.write("" + result + "\n");
                out.flush();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Doing this way you don't need to worry about closing the resources yourself.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! If you don't mind, could you explain what it's the difference between BufferedWriter and PrintWriter? I've tried to understand the difference before but I couldn't.

Comment: You can't close the stream inside the loop because when the next time you try to use them they are already closed. Closing resources yourself is hard in Java because the close operation itself can throw an exception. Because of this in Java 7 is better to use the try-with-resources technique.

Comment: A BufferedWriter uses a buffer in memory to write to a stream, so is more efficient. With a  PrintWriter you can write formatted text to a stream by using methods like println.

Comment: Makes sense. Understood now. Thank you!